# Calculate the difference in population between two years in SQL?

Tags: sql

I would like to know how to calculate the difference in population of two years using SQL. The table has three columns: country, year and population. For more information you can check out Question 8 from this link: https://www.codecademy.com/practice/projects/world-populations-sql-practice

I have tried the codes below but the first one required manual calculation and the other didn't work.

```
SELECT population, year FROM population_years
WHERE country = 'Indonesia' AND year = 2000 
OR country = 'Indonesia' AND year = 2010;

SELECT 
(SELECT population, year FROM population_years
WHERE country = 'Indonesia' AND year = 2000) -
(SELECT population, year FROM population_years
WHERE country = 'Indonesia' AND year = 2010)
```

The population of Indonesia in 2010 and 2000 are 242M and 214M.

So what can I write to my query so that it returns 28M?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may join 2000 record with 2010 record:

```
SELECT p10.population - p00.population
FROM population_years p00
    JOIN  population_years p10 ON p10.country = p00.country 
                              AND p10.year = 2010
WHERE p00.country = 'Indonesia' 
  AND p00.year = 2000
```

Comment: That's not technically a "cross join", just a join. Anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Transact-SQL, you could use the LAG() function:

```
SELECT X.MIN_YR_POP, X.MAX_YR_POP, X.NET_POP_VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT PY.population AS [MAX_YR_POP], LAG(PY.population, 10, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year) AS [MIN_YR_POP]
    ,   CONVERT(FLOAT, PY.population) - CONVERT(FLOAT, LAG(PY.population, 10, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year)) AS [NET_POP_VALUE]
    FROM #_pop_yrs AS PY
) AS X
WHERE X.MIN_YR_POP IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
MAX_YR_POP  MIN_YR_POP  NET_POP_VALUE
242.96834   214.67661   28.29173
```

The LAG() function takes a scalar value, offset value, and default value (if nothing works or you go out of scope), then returns a table with desired values aligned.  For the subquery above, with a lag of 10, the output would look something like this:

```
year    MAX_YR_POP  MIN_YR_POP  NET_POP_VALUE
2000    214.67661   NULL    NULL
2001    217.83628   NULL    NULL
2002    220.97191   NULL    NULL
2003    223.06967   NULL    NULL
2004    226.00413   NULL    NULL
2005    228.89575   NULL    NULL
2006    231.82024   NULL    NULL
2007    234.694     NULL    NULL
2008    237.51236   NULL    NULL
2009    240.27152   NULL    NULL
2010    242.96834   214.67661   28.29173
```

You get a lot of undesired results, so we made that a subquery and took what we wanted.

Note that for LAG(), you can't use negative offset values; we can't look back 10 rows by using -10.  Instead, you have to know the order of your table and adjust accordingly.  If we wanted to reverse our results, we could have our year value be descending:

```
OVER(ORDER BY PY.year DESC)
```

And this updated query:

```
SELECT PY.population AS [MAX_YR_POP], LAG(PY.population, 10, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year DESC) AS [MIN_YR_POP]
,   CONVERT(FLOAT, PY.population) - CONVERT(FLOAT, LAG(PY.population, 10, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year DESC)) AS [NET_POP_VALUE]
FROM #_pop_yrs AS PY
```

Would return this:

```
year    MAX_YR_POP  MIN_YR_POP  NET_POP_VALUE
2010    242.96834   NULL    NULL
2009    240.27152   NULL    NULL
2008    237.51236   NULL    NULL
2007    234.694     NULL    NULL
2006    231.82024   NULL    NULL
2005    228.89575   NULL    NULL
2004    226.00413   NULL    NULL
2003    223.06967   NULL    NULL
2002    220.97191   NULL    NULL
2001    217.83628   NULL    NULL
2000    214.67661   242.96834   -28.29173
```

Our 2010 population value is now at the top, while the 2000 value is at the bottom.  We're masters of our universe, though, so we can apply ORDER BY to the whole query and correct the output:

```
SELECT PY.year, PY.population AS [MAX_YR_POP], LAG(PY.population, 10, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year DESC) AS [MIN_YR_POP]
,   CONVERT(FLOAT, PY.population) - CONVERT(FLOAT, LAG(PY.population, 10, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year DESC)) AS [NET_POP_VALUE]
FROM #_pop_yrs AS PY
ORDER BY PY.year
```

And:

```
year    MAX_YR_POP  MIN_YR_POP  NET_POP_VALUE
2000    214.67661   242.96834   -28.29173
2001    217.83628   NULL    NULL
2002    220.97191   NULL    NULL
2003    223.06967   NULL    NULL
2004    226.00413   NULL    NULL
2005    228.89575   NULL    NULL
2006    231.82024   NULL    NULL
2007    234.694     NULL    NULL
2008    237.51236   NULL    NULL
2009    240.27152   NULL    NULL
2010    242.96834   NULL    NULL
```

Might not be the best solution for your question, but it might be applicable down the line at some point! Note, there's also a LEAD() function that looks ahead a number of rows.

EDIT: If you're ambitious and want to get all the values without using a CURSOR, then you could iterate the whole thing.  Here's an example that calculates pretty much all of the combinations while skipping over any null years. It probably needs some tweaking.

```
DECLARE @_results TABLE (
      year1 CHAR(4),
      year2 CHAR(4),
      pop1 FLOAT,
      pop2 FLOAT,
      net_pop FLOAT
)

DECLARE @_count INT = 1
WHILE (@_count <= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #_pop_yrs))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @_results
        SELECT X.[year1], X.[year2], X.[pop1], X.[pop2], ROUND(X.[net_pop], 5) AS [net_pop]
        FROM (
            SELECT PY.year AS [year1]
            ,   LAG(PY.year, @_count, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year) AS [year2]
            ,   PY.population AS [pop1]
            ,   LAG(PY.population, @_count, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year) AS [pop2]
            ,   CONVERT(FLOAT, PY.population) - CONVERT(FLOAT, LAG(PY.population, @_count, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY PY.year)) AS [net_pop]
            FROM #_pop_yrs AS PY
        ) AS X
        WHERE X.[year1] IS NOT NULL AND X.year2 IS NOT NULL
        SET @_count += 1
    END

SELECT *
FROM @_results
ORDER BY year1, year2
```

Output:

```
year1   year2   pop1        pop2        net_pop
2001    2000    217.83628   214.67661   3.15967
2002    2000    220.97191   214.67661   6.2953
2002    2001    220.97191   217.83628   3.13563
2003    2000    223.06967   214.67661   8.39306
2003    2001    223.06967   217.83628   5.23339
2003    2002    223.06967   220.97191   2.09776
2004    2000    226.00413   214.67661   11.32752
2004    2001    226.00413   217.83628   8.16785
2004    2002    226.00413   220.97191   5.03222
2004    2003    226.00413   223.06967   2.93446
2005    2000    228.89575   214.67661   14.21914
2005    2001    228.89575   217.83628   11.05947
2005    2002    228.89575   220.97191   7.92384
2005    2003    228.89575   223.06967   5.82608
2005    2004    228.89575   226.00413   2.89162
2006    2000    231.82024   214.67661   17.14363
2006    2001    231.82024   217.83628   13.98396
2006    2002    231.82024   220.97191   10.84833
2006    2003    231.82024   223.06967   8.75057
2006    2004    231.82024   226.00413   5.81611
2006    2005    231.82024   228.89575   2.92449
2007    2000    234.694     214.67661   20.01739
2007    2001    234.694     217.83628   16.85772
2007    2002    234.694     220.97191   13.72209
2007    2003    234.694     223.06967   11.62433
2007    2004    234.694     226.00413   8.68987
2007    2005    234.694     228.89575   5.79825
2007    2006    234.694     231.82024   2.87376
2008    2000    237.51236   214.67661   22.83575
2008    2001    237.51236   217.83628   19.67608
2008    2002    237.51236   220.97191   16.54045
2008    2003    237.51236   223.06967   14.44269
2008    2004    237.51236   226.00413   11.50823
2008    2005    237.51236   228.89575   8.61661
2008    2006    237.51236   231.82024   5.69212
2008    2007    237.51236   234.694     2.81836
2009    2000    240.27152   214.67661   25.59491
2009    2001    240.27152   217.83628   22.43524
2009    2002    240.27152   220.97191   19.29961
2009    2003    240.27152   223.06967   17.20185
2009    2004    240.27152   226.00413   14.26739
2009    2005    240.27152   228.89575   11.37577
2009    2006    240.27152   231.82024   8.45128
2009    2007    240.27152   234.694     5.57752
2009    2008    240.27152   237.51236   2.75916
2010    2000    242.96834   214.67661   28.29173
2010    2001    242.96834   217.83628   25.13206
2010    2002    242.96834   220.97191   21.99643
2010    2003    242.96834   223.06967   19.89867
2010    2004    242.96834   226.00413   16.96421
2010    2005    242.96834   228.89575   14.07259
2010    2006    242.96834   231.82024   11.1481
2010    2007    242.96834   234.694     8.27434
2010    2008    242.96834   237.51236   5.45598
2010    2009    242.96834   240.27152   2.69682
```